# Django and Ajax. Right way of infinite scroll implement

Tags: python, ajax, django, pymongo, mongoengine

I've got a page where user selects some tags, then in my view I make an aggregate-query to the mongodb and return a result depending on tags selected. There are a lot of documents, that's why I only display only fixed number of them. I want to use infinite scroll with ajax.

So when user scrolls down, Ajax-request with $limit and $skip values is passing to my view, getting to .is_ajax() part, and getting back values from Command Cursor aggregate-query.

Is it a right way to do such things in Django? I'm new in it and didn't experienced with such things.

I'm using Django 1.8 and mongoengine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but if you allow the user to set $limit and $skip, you're opening yourself up to letting a malicious user setting `$skip = 0`, and `$limit = 'some_large_number'`, to try and overload your server. You're better off just requesting the page number, and using that to calculate on the server which results to show. [Here is a tutorial showing a working example](http://samscheding1.pythonanywhere.com/blog/post/django-ajax-infinite-scroll) (Full Disclaimer, I wrote the tutorial). Let me know if you need anything further explained.

Answer (score 1):

The following link has some good ideas about endless pagination. Give it a try :
http://alexkehayias.tumblr.com/post/15724356031/infinite-scroll-django

Another option is to use the following app :  http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html